# How do I set/clear the Windows archive bit with cygwin's find/chmod?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Yes, I know, the archive bit is evil.

That being said, is there support for querying it with 'find', and modifying it with 'chmod'?

My googling has turned up nothing......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by Jed, you can use attrib both to query and to set the archive bit. You must however remember to use the cygpath tool to convert between cygwin style file names and DOS style names, as required by attrib.

If you convert the output of find with cygpath, invoke attrib for each file name and use egrep to check for lines starting with A (regexp '^A'), you should be able to search for files with the archive bit set.

Answer (score 1):

When I used cygwin, I made sure it had access to the Windows tools as well. In that case, you can use `attrib` to at least set or clear the archive bit for you.

To list files with the archive bit set you can use `dir /A:A`, which you can accomplish by doing `CMD /c` or something similar.

I don't think you're going to find the ability to do this in Unix tools.